# convert mongodb object to javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I pass a config file to another node.js module when starting it. The config file contain the following json:

```
    "resolution": {
      "activated": true,
      "types": [
      {"of": 23}
      ]
    }
```

When I print the received types array in the called node.js module, it looks like

```
console.log('types array: '+ this.config.resolution.types) 
//output
types array: [object Object]
```

if I tried to print the text by using `JSON.stringify()`, I get the following result

```
[{"of":23}]
```

My problem start when I try to replace the types array with a list retried from a mongodb database. my code looks like:

"resolution": {
      "activated": true,
      "types": [
      savedTypes
      ]
    }

Now when I print the received types config, it looks like this:

```
types array: { _id: 5ab9fe8fd1f64303cd98f122, of: 23, __v: 0 }
```

and the called node module is not working properly with this config. How can I cast this to an object? I tried to use

```
JSON.parse(savedTypes)
```

and get the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 2
```

Comment: Share your mongodb query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use mongoose, I think that the correct form is using ToJSON() function.

Otherwise, you can use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); But I think that de first form is better.

=)

Comment: Why don't you use lean() in mongoose, user.find({}).lean() like this

Comment: @MariyaJames yes! it is right! =) but I don't know if he need mongoose objects.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could use `.toObject()` method from javascript to convert mongoose object into javascript object.

Here is a reference link to dig out more

https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-tojson-toobject-transform-with-subdocuments/