# Why an array (in mongoose schema) element is not being removed using splice method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

In my Nodejs app, I have an array called auditors_checklist of type post (post is mongoose schema) which i have refrenced to user model in mongoose schema, now i want to remove an element from this array for a specific user , i have used ajax request, when "clear" button is clicked request is made to this route:-

```
router.get("/clear/:slug", (req,res)=>{

  User.findById(req.user._id).populate("auditors_checklist").exec(function(err,user){
    for(var i=0;i<user.auditors_checklist.length;i++){
      console.log("\n",user.auditors_checklist[i],"\n")
    }

    if(err) console.log(err)
    else{
        Post.findOne({slug: req.params.slug}, (err,post)=>{

        if(err) console.log(err)
        else{
          
          for(var i=0;i<user.auditors_checklist.length;i++){
            // console.log("flag : " + flag)
            // console.log(user.auditors_checklist[i].title, post.title)
            if(user.auditors_checklist[i].title === post.title){
              user.auditors_checklist.splice(i ,1);
              break;
            }
          }
          
          // console.log("flag : " + flag);
          // console.log(delete_index)
          console.log(user.auditors_checklist.length)
          // user.auditors_checklist.splice(delete_index ,1)          
          console.log(user.auditors_checklist.length,"\n\n\n")

          for(var i=0;i<user.auditors_checklist.length;i++){
            console.log("\n",user.auditors_checklist[i],"\n")
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

I printed the size of this array before and after splice operation on the console , it actually shows array size decreased by one and which means the post gets deleted , but when i check it in the mongo shell using db.users.find({username: "name"}), it is not deleted, the array element (array element is actually an object) is still there ?

how is this possible? And how do i actually delete that element ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to convert mongoose object to js object check here for 
 lean() in mongoose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508700/convert-mongodb-object-to-javascript-object

Comment: you need to save the new array again

Comment: yes , it is working , i forgot to save it again , i did user.save(), now it's working, thanks for the help @Ifaruki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose has a built-in function to remove an element from an array of sub-documents.

```
 document.array.pull(element);
 // or if you want to look with a key
 document.array.pull(_id: element);
 // you can pull multiple elements
 document.array.pull(element1, element2);
```

Your code will be

```
router.get("/clear/:slug", (req,res)=>{
  User
   .findById(req.user._id)
   .populate("auditors_checklist")
   .exec(function(err,user){

     if(err) console.log(err)
     else{
         Post.findOne({slug: req.params.slug}, (err,post)=>{

         if(err) console.log(err)
         else{
           user.auditors_checklist.pull(post.title);
           user.save((error,user)=>{
           //TODO
         }); 
      }
    });
   }
});
```

Source: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-pull