# Why cannot react catch an error from the node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, registry, react-fullstack

I build a register page using React as Frontend, and Node Js as backend. However, when I try to check the delicate username. Axios from the Frontend doesn't show any error. I have written the catch in many different ways. But I still cannot find where the problem is. Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

Frontend

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if (handleValidation()) {
      await axios.post(registerRoute, {
        username,
        email,
        password,
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch((error) => {
         if (error.response.status === 11000) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
         }
      })
      navigate("/");
    }
  };
```

Backend

```js
module.exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
   const { username, email, password } = req.body;

   if (!username || typeof username !== 'string') {
      return res.json({status: 'error', message: 'Invalid username'})
   }

    const usernameExit = await Users.findOne({username: username})
    if (usernameExit) {
       return res.status(11000).json({ message: "Username already exit" });
    }

   if (!password || typeof password !== 'string') {
      return res.json({status: 'error', message: 'Invalid password'})
   }

  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 2); 
    const user = new Users({
      username,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });
    user.save();
    delete user.password;
    return res.json({ status: true, user });
  } catch (error) {
   if (error.code === 11000) {
      return res.status(11000).json({ message: "Username already exit" });
   }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. In your back end endpoint you need to add the word await in before saving the document since you're using async/await for this method.

```
await user.save();
```

Second, you won't be able to delete the user's password this way because this is a MongoDB document and not a JavaScript object. You can convert the document to be a JS object which was explained in this question below. After you convert it to a JS object then you do delete user.password, not before.

[convert mongodb object to javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508700/convert-mongodb-object-to-javascript-object)

Third, you should always follow the industry best practices and use one of the HTTPS codes based on the situation. This way you know that a MongoDB error code is coming from MongoDB and not your endpoint because you setup a different status code like 404 or 400 for any custom error handling that you are doing.

Here's the reference for the HTTPS codes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

If you want to catch the status in Axios, you need to set the status like @Yozi mentioned and follow the approach below

```
return res.status(400).json({message: "Some message here", user});
```

This way Axios will catch the 400 status and throw an error in the console. If you customize the status like

```
res.json({status: 'error'});
```

You need to handle that differently in your front end. You can do something like

```
console.log(res.data.status === 'error');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `return res.json({status: 'error', message: 'Invalid password'})`
   It returns status 200, which is not an error (axios know nothing about your  `status: "error"` thing.
2. status `11000` does not sound right to me. Normally it is something below 600. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). In your case, I would use 422.

So, for all your errors add `status(422)` and check if it works.

Comment: 11000 is a mongodb error - Duplicate key. You can see more here @Yozi https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2284

Comment: @LeonardoNoronhaSantos I mean, it is ok to have `11000` in mongo, but you set 11000 for HTTP status code, it does not sound right. `res.status(11000)` here - I would use 422

Comment: I agree, you should never mix mongodb error codes with your own stuff.

Comment: @Yozi@LeonardoNoronhaSantos Thanks, guys. It works. However, I got one more question. After I set the HTTP status to 422. It will not show any error message on the server side. Do we need to show the error message on both Frontend and Backend? If it's necessary how can I console the same error on the server side too?

Comment: @DavidLew Yes, you handled the error in your backend code and it is not an exception anymore, so there are no additional messages. If you want to log this situation, you can use a simple `console.log`/`console.warn`/`console.error`, or (better) use something like [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) for better customizations

Comment: @Yozi, I will try to figure out how to use Winston. Thanks again.